# putc in c programming in files

Tags: c

Im just creating my own library on file handling to make it more flexible,but I got stucked up at these point watch these below program

```
int filewrite(char *filename,unsigned char number)
{
    FILE *dill;

    if((dill=fopen(filename,"r"))==0)
        return(0);// error no such file exists  returns 0
    else
    {

        if(number==0)
        {
            dill=fopen(filename,"w");

            while(number!='x')
            {
                number=getche();
                putc(number,dill);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dill=fopen(filename,"a+");

            while(number!='x')
            {
                number=getche();
                putc(number,dill);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for instance I made the condition not equal to x so if I enter x letter it gets terminated, 
but I want that to be used too.but what is the condition to be put to use all letters numbers and special symbols when we are writing into a file becuase If I hit enter then it goes to next line but its not terminating and I want to use enter too but how to say that this is the EOF using putc ? Help me guys

Comment: So you want the `while` loop to terminate when you hit return?

Comment: no I need newline sometimes in my texting file so I do not want enter to be in condition anyother clue?linus

Comment: You wrote: *If I hit enter then it goes to next line but its not terminating*. Please try to be more exact.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to terminate when you press enter you can change the while loop to this:

```
while((number != 'x') && (number != '\r'))
{
    number=getche();
    putc(number,dill);
}
```

You should also close your file pointers using `fclose(dill)` to make sure the stream is flushed and the files aren't left opened when your program terminates.

Comment: Note that getche() is a non-standard function that will not work on most compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly (I'm not saying I do), You want to be able to enter any character into the file stream but also be able to terminate the stream by hitting the character **'x'**. If that's what you're asking then this is not possible. You will have to come up with another way to terminate your stream. For instance you can try detecting if CTRL + another button is pressed instead of **'x'**.

Comment: thats what i want dark but how to put CTRL in condition it says undefined

Comment: I would then recommend you trap a signal such as CTRL+C or something similar.. and use the signal handler to cleanly terminate the stream. This is a good example of trapping and implementing a signal handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c (answer 3)