# Prevent C program from getting killed with ctrl-c

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Catch Ctrl-C in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c)

I am writing a C command line program and trying to ensure that ctrl-c won't kill it. Any ideas of how I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you press Ctrl-C while a program is running, what happens underneath is that your process receives a signal called SIGINT, the default action when a process receives this signal is to terminate itself.
So your goal should be to modify this behavior:
Use the function `signal` to catch the signal sent to your process when ctrl-c

you should go with something like this:

```
signal(SIGINT, handler_function);//handler_function is a void returning function that takes one int paramter, you can do nothing there if you just want to prevent your process from terminating.
```

P.S Here's the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) for further information :D 
P.P.S If you're not familier with what a signal is, please refer to [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) if you find something confusing there, let us know.

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas of how I can do that

Ignore `SIGINT` using a SIG_IGN disposition or catch it in a do-nothing handler. In some implementations there's even a `sigignore` function.

Anyways, you should be fine with:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

`SIG_IGN` is sppecified in C11-7.14 so it's as portable as it gets.