# How to keep input before CTRL-C

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu

With this code I found here on Stack:

```
...
char buffer[256]

while((count=read(0, buffer, 256)) > 1)
   {
   if(buffer[count] = '\n') break;
   }

   buffer[n-1] ='\0';
```

I can read from the standard input, but I have 2 questions:

1. Why is `'='` used in the if() instead of `'=='`?
2. If I press `CTRL-C` after writing something, how can I keep what I
   wrote?

Thanks

Comment: The use of `=` rather than `==` is probably a typo. It doesn't make sense otherwise. Also, it should probably be `if (buffer[count-1] == '\n')`.

Comment: It is definitely not a typo, read returns read count. while read count is larger than 1 while loop runs.

Comment: @Armin: The question is about the `=` in the `if`, not the `while`.

Comment: @user315052 Correct , i totally missed if(), Daniel Fischer was right.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is '=' used in the if() instead of '=='?

In the if-statement, it's probably a typo. Because

```
buffer[count] = '\n'
```

will always be '\n', and in C thats "true" (non-null).

> If I press CTRL-C after writing something, how can I keep what I wrote?

Pressing CTRL-C in the terminal will send a SIGINT to the running process. Normally your application will immediately quit, no matter what it was doing.

You can catch the SIGINT-event with [some lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217052/2165444), but whats the point of "keeping what you wrote"?

Comment: `buffer[count]` is also off by one. `^C` usually generates `SIGINT`.

Comment: Changed it to `SIGINT`. And yes, `buffer[count]` seems to be off by one.

Comment: "intermediately" -> "immediately"?

Comment: @undur_gongor: Of course ;) English is not my first language, so I'm using a spell checker. And I clicked the wrong suggestion.

Comment: I agree that it makes little sense to keep what I wrote, but that is one of the purposes of this exercise. By the way, does the condition in the while even get to run?

Comment: @user2170647 The condition of the `if` will always run, buffer[count] = '\n' evaluates to `\n` , which is non-zero, which in C is true.