# How to break a while loop in C on linux by taking any value from keyboard?

Tags: c, linux, while-loop

The program I am building runs in an infinite while loop with a switch case in it. I want to insert a while loop under each case and perform few operations in the loop, but the loop should exit as soon as a keyboard input is given. So that after taking the input from keyboard another case is run with the nested while loop in it, and the process continues.

The structure is:

```
while()//infinite loop
    {
    ...............      //operations
    ...............      //operations
    switch()
        {
        case 1:
        ...............    //operations
        ...............    //operations
        while()//infinite loop
             {
             ..............
             ..............
             exit if there is any input from keyboard
             }
        break;

        case 2:
        ...............    //operations
        ...............    //operations
        while()//infinite loop
             {
             ..............
             ..............
             exit if there is any input from keyboard
             }
        break;


        case n:
        ...............    //operations
        ...............    //operations
        while()//infinite loop
             {
             ..............
             ..............
             exit if there is any input from keyboard
             }
        break;
        }
  }
```

Is there any way to do it???

Comment: Are you asking how to get keyboard input, or how to break nested loops?

Comment: Are you asking how to do raw input, so that waiting ends as soon as _any_ key that produces a char or control code is pressed, as opposed to being forced to press enter (after optionally inputting some text)?

Comment: Regardless of the solution to the keyboard problem, this function should be refactored.

Comment: I need to know how to break the nested loop with a keyboard input, so that, that input is fed to the case again as the outer while loop is run. What I am planning to do is, when a key is pressed and the nested while loop breaks, that key is written into a file. Then this key is taken as an input from the file, for the switch when the outer while loop runs again.

Comment: Indeed, waiting could be done after the switch, once for all cases, instead of code duplication.

Comment: You could use the ncurses library and its `getch()` function. There are a few examples available on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have You considered using threads ? One thread monitors keyboard, second is main loop ? Also You might try using signals, and for example wrap ctrl-c signal, which will set and clear flag in all loops ?

Comment: On Linux, learning about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), perhaps [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) libraries could help you significantly. You still need to master the C programming language. There are good books for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you people.... even though my answer is a little out of box, I think ring0's approach is much better.
Here is what I did.

- Added code inside the outer while loop which allows the compiler to take argument for switch case from a file, say, data.dat
- Added similar code in each of the nested while loops to continue if the variable retrieved from the data.dat is what is required to run the loop, if not, break.
- Since in linux I can run processes in the back ground, I ran the main program in the background, and edited data.dat accordingly.

This method is working for me but will definitely try ring0's method too.

Answer (score 6):

Linux keyboard input is buffered, in order to catch a key that was hit on the fly you have to configure TERM IO.

Near the top of *main()* add a call to (*see code below*)

```
term_nonblocking();
```

to read a key that was pressed on the fly, without waiting for a carriage return (CR).

Code:

```
struct termios stdin_orig;  // Structure to save parameters

void term_reset() {
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&stdin_orig);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&stdin_orig);
}

void term_nonblocking() {
        struct termios newt;
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &stdin_orig);
        fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // non-blocking
        newt = stdin_orig;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

        atexit(term_reset);
}
```

Note: `term_reset()` will be called automatically when your program exits, (to reset the terminal parameters).

You can call the now non-blocking `getchar()` anywhere in your program to detect a key press

```
int i = getchar();
```

and check if a key was pressed:

```
if (i > 0) {
    // key was pressed, code in `i`
}
```

In your program for instance:

```
int key = 0;

while (... && key <= 0) {
   // ... 
   key = getchar();
}
```

Note: if you want the *output* to be unbuffered, call `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`

(comment from @stacey : *getchar()* may return 0 or -1 when no key is available)

Comment: You might want to `ungetc(i, stdin)` if you read a character so that it can be processed again by the outer loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. This is valuable information indeed.

Comment: Note that getchar() returns -1 or 0 if a key hasn't been pressed. I used `(key <= 0)` in my while condition to get around this. As it stands, the while loop ends immediately if nothing is pressed.

Comment: @stacey thanks, edited the answer as it may help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar desire for an old system that I have to maintain.  I wanted to add a "quit" as well as provide some timing. I stripped out all proprietary code and left the shell of what I learned from this site. Thank you.

I ended up using the above example by [ring0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338904/ring%C3%B8). I wanted to comment but I'm not at that level yet.

I also took some information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c) by [Ulf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954886/ulf-gjerdingen) and [Walter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497394/walter)

I could not use fcntl because of a global variable that was used in our code that conflicted with something within fcntl and I did not want to figure out how to avoid that conflict.

Anyway, here is an example. It worked for me on Debian (older version). Your mileage may vary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define SLEEP  500000. /*usec*/

#include <termios.h>
struct termios stdin_orig;

void term_reset() {
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &stdin_orig);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &stdin_orig);
}

void term_nonblocking() { 
  struct termios term;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &stdin_orig);
  term = stdin_orig;
  term.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;
  //term.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL | IXON | IXOFF);
  term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);// | ECHO | ECHOK | ECHOE | ECHONL | ISIG | IEXTEN);*/
  term.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  /*   fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // non-blocking */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
} 
// end mikes timing

int main (void)
{
  int key=0;
  // mikes test variables
  long mnloops = 0;
  double mttot = 0.0;//total time elapsed in difference between start-end.
  term_nonblocking();
  // end mikes test variables

  /*main loop*/
  do{
    //mikes timing
    puts("Start Do");
    time_t mnow;
    struct timeval mtv;
    struct timezone mtz;
    time(&mnow);
    gettimeofday(&mtv, &mtz);
    double startTime = (double)mnow + mtv.tv_usec/1e6;
    // end mikes timing
    usleep(SLEEP);
    puts("got hey");
    //mikes timing
    time(&mnow);
    gettimeofday(&mtv, &mtz);
    mttot += (((double)mnow + mtv.tv_usec/1e6) - startTime);
    mnloops++;
    key = getchar();
    // end mikes timing
  }while (1 && key != 'q');/* end of main loop*/
  term_reset();
  printf("DONE: average time per loop = %-10.4e\n",mttot/mnloops);
  return 0;
}
```