# How to end a whileloop with ctrl+c in c on windows?

Tags: c, windows, eof

So i need to write an whileloop for a program that's supposed to prompt the user with this:

```
char vector[10];
while(????){
    print("Write a number");
    scanf("%s",vector);
}

printf("Goodbye");
```

The program is supposed to print goodbye and close when the user presses ctrl+c.
Im pretty sure I cant use putchar in this case?

Comment: @ajay What is the EOF character? The constant EOF is a constant that should be different from any other character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static end_flag = 0;

BOOL WINAPI controlHandler(DWORD type){
    if(type == CTRL_C_EVENT){
        end_flag = 1;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main(){
    char vector[10];

    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(controlHandler, TRUE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed SetConsoleCtrlHandler");
        return -1;
    }
    while(!end_flag){
        printf("Write a number ");
        scanf("%s",vector);
    }

    printf("Goodbye");
    return 0;
}
```

---

CTRL+Z version

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char vector[10];

    while(1){
        printf("Write a number ");
        if(scanf("%s", vector)==EOF)//press CTRL+Z
            break;
    }

    printf("Goodbye");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks ,it works!, and ouch, super complicated for me, one more problem I have is actually that there are lines of code in the whileloop that I don't want to run after the user has pressed ctrl+c? are there any rescues?

Comment: @Tensora I think that it use `exit(1)` instead of setting the flag.

Comment: the ctrl+z version works fine since it brakes it now, however it prints z^ and then the user has to press enter one time before it quits the loop. I have some real trouble with this

Comment: what I mean is, is there any way to make the program quit the loop without pressing enter afterwards?

Comment: @Tensora  use getch or kbhit or key-status ...., but in everything yourself do. It is not realistic because no longer do without preparing. you do to CTRL+C and exit.

Answer (score 0):

see https://superuser.com/questions/214239/whats-the-command-prompts-equivalent-to-cygwins-ctrlz:

> Depends on what you mean by "quit something"; within Windows cmd:
>
> Ctrl+Z sends the EOF character, which could terminate a process if
>   you're providing input, but otherwise will probably do nothing.
>
> Ctrl+C normally sends SIGINT to the foreground process, which should
>   terminate it, but programs can respond however they like - ie, they
>   can catch the signal but then ignore it. The command can also be
>   remapped to other jobs (such that for a specific program it doesn't
>   really send a signal) or ignored entirely.
>
> Ctrl+Break always sends SIGBREAK, which again should terminate the
>   process, but unlike Ctrl+C cannot be remapped, but can still be
>   ignored. This is probably what you need.

Comment: I think we are supposed to use the EOF, but I just want to get out of the whileloop with some kind of ctrl+?

Comment: thanks, the exercise is actually to end the whileloop with ctrl+D in Linux, what would be the same on windows?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Post similar to this one on Stack Overflow:
[Catch Ctrl-C in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c)

You might want to check it out. Cheers!

Comment: thanks, the exercise is actually to end I with ctrl+D in Linux, what would be the the same on windows?