# Conditional signal catch

Tags: c, keyboard, signals, cat, ctrl

I know my title may be confusing, but bear with me. I'm new to signals.

I have a program that acts like the `cat` or `more` unix commands, but it has a little twist. It prints out the first x lines and then allows the user to press Ctrl-/ to print out the next x lines. I know `Ctrl-/` is by default used to stop the process, but I want to override it.

I want to do something along the lines of

`if (user_enters = signal(SIGQUIT, sig_function))`
then print the next x lines

I'm not sure how to conditionally check if the user entered the `Ctrl-/` signal

right now my code forces the user to enter n to go to the next x lines, like so...

```
        scanf(" %c", &next);
        if (next == 'n'){
          //loop +4 times and only print the last 4 lines
          for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("%s", buf);
            if (i < 3){
              if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file) == NULL){
                fclose(file);
                return 0;
              }
            }
          }
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: signals catching must be explictly handled by calling `signal()` (or better `sigaction()`).

Comment: right but how can I conditionally check if the signal has been inputted? should I put the conditional block inside the function called by `signal(sig, function)`  ?

Comment: nevermind, I can see the correct method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c

Comment: yes, you have a function that's called by the signal. Depend to you then to deal with that information (as it breaks the execution flow you may have to deal with global flags).