# How to clean up local data in SIGINT handler

Tags: c, signals, blocking, sigint

I need to execute clean up functions in SIGINT handler, but I can't pass local data to it. Here an example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct database *db = db_cursor();
    sockfd_t master_socket = init_server();

    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    while (1) {
        // accepting connections
    }
}

void sigint_handler(int s) {
    destroy_db(db);
    shutdown(master_socket, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(master_socket);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

How can I implement such behaviour? I've tried make this variables are global, but
I can't invoke this functions at compile time (error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant).

Comment: You shouldn't do all of this logic in the handler itself.  Just have it set a flag, and test for the flag in the main loop.

Comment: Adding up to Oliver's comment: Type the flag `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: Now it works, but I have blocking calls like `accept`, and when I invoke `SIGINT` it doesn't stop immediately. Should I use multiplexing to address this issue?

Comment: If `accept()` doesn't return, create this signal-handler using `sigaction()` instead of `signal()`  and unset the `SA_RESTART` flag in the member `sa_flags` of the structure passed.

Comment: You don't need to block on accept(): just set the listening socket to non-blocking, add it to the select()ed (or polled) set, and check the flag whenever select() returns -1/EINTR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only a very limited number of functions is guaranteed to be async-signal-safe and therefore may be called from within a signal handler, `exit()` f.e. does not belong to them.

Take a different approach:

```
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigint_received = 0; /* volatile might be necessary depending on 
                                              the system/implementation in use. 
                                              (see "C11 draft standard n1570: 5.1.2.3")*/

void sigint_handler(int s) 
{
  sigint_received = 1;
}

int main(void) 
{
  signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

  while (!sigint_received) 
  {
    /* Do stuff. */
  }

  /* Clean up here. */
}
```

For more on this see

- the Linux man-page here [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)
- the [POSIX specifications here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)

---

Note: To be maximal portable you want to use `sigaction()` instead of `signal()`.

The code to replace `signal()` might look like this:

```
struct sigaction sa = 
{
  sigint_handler
  /*, SA_RESTART */ /* Set this by if blocking calls like read() or accept() 
                       should _not_ return on signal reception. */
};

if (-1 == sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL))
{
  perror("sigaction() failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Documentation on `sigaction()`:

- [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)
- [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)

Comment: `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: No. Why do you think this is needed? @EOF

Comment: The signal disposition is done via the OS *to* the process. No external devices is changing anything here.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.3 Program execution 5 When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits, as
does the state of the floating-point environment if it is modified by the handler and not restored to its original state.*

Comment: @EOF Hm, fair enough, from the part of the standard quoted, it looks as if qualifying the `sig_atomic_t` as `volatile` is required, depending on the implementation. (Other parts of the Standard (7.14/2)  aren't such explicit.)

Comment: n1570 *7.14.1.1/5* has similar provisions (with some exceptions), which are also found in the earlier C99 draft standard n1256.