# why doesn't std::vector free its memory after a user interrupt?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, stdvector

In case a user sent the `SIGINT` interrupt ( *or any other interrupt that would interrupt program execution* ) to a program, why does the std::vector deallocator fail to run automatically in such a case?

i used this test code to try it out:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main(void) {
  vector<int> buf(40, 0);

  int i{};
  for (;;) {
    printf("!my great program: %d\n", buf[i]);
    ++i;
  }

  return 0; // a pipe dream
}
```

i compiled it with debug symbols using `gcc` and ran it through `valgrind` using this command:
`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v --log-file=val.log ./prog`

after running the program through `valgrind` i got this as the heap summary:

```
...
==602714== HEAP SUMMARY:
==602714==     in use at exit: 73,888 bytes in 3 blocks
==602714==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 73,888 bytes allocated
...
```

Comment: your process has been terminated and all of its memory is gone, just ignore valgrind

Comment: The `SIGINT` **interrupted** the program, so the program could not destruct the `buf`.

Comment: Seems like SIGINT causes abnormal termination. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072493/822455