# How to restore the normal terminal when Ctrl+C is pressed?

Tags: c, terminal

I have created a digital clock program. I use this cmd

```
printf("\033[?25l");
            // Hiding the cursor
```

but when I stop the program with Ctrl+C
the terminal cursor is still hidden.
How do I solve this problem
and restore the cursor after Ctrl+C?

Comment: Write a signal handler to unhide the cursor when ctrl-c is entered. Note that only [async safe functions](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) should be called in a signal handler and `printf` is not one of them. So you need to either use `write` or set a variable and let the main program do the `printf`.

Comment: Another way would be not to hide the cursor but to locate it where it isn't so obviously noticed, for example at the bottom right of a frame.

Comment: how can u explain by code

Comment: By postioning the cursor with a `gotoxy` call or terminal sequence in a similar way, before and after printing the time. The actual method would be terminal or system specific. For example on Windows I would use the API call `SetConsoleCursorPosition()`.

Comment: [Catch Ctrl-C in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch Ctrl-C in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c)

Comment: You should also unhide it when `Ctrl-Z` is pressed (i.e. also catch `SIGTSTP`) and hide it back on `SIGCONT`. And also handle `SIGTERM` similarly to `SIGINT`. It's fine to do `printf("\033[...")` to get a grip of how things work, but in general, better use `curses` which will do all that for you, and also take care of using the correct escapes for your terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
        static volatile int continueRunning = 1;// 
        void intHandler(int dummy) {
             printf("\033c");// clear the console
             printf("\e[?25h");//To re-enable the cursor
                 continueRunning = 0;
        }
    
    
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv) // you can use like this int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
    {
        signal(SIGINT, intHandler);
      
        
            while (continueRunning) {
/// to continuue your code
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, one is not allowed to call `printf` in a signal handler.