# How to read Ctrl+C as input

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal

(in **Linux**)

The methods I found all use `signal` .

Is there no other way? Is there anything I can do to make the terminal put it into the input buffer?

Comment: Using `signal` is the correct way. Why can you not use it? It's not difficult.

Comment: No, there isn't. Also, see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Bib Because I think it seems troublesome

Comment: It's not troublesome. It's incredibly easy. It take just a few lines. Remember, you learn by doing.

Comment: There *are* alternatives – [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and on linux actually [`eventfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) – none of these are as simple to use as `signal`, though. In any case, all three catch the signal that is sent to the process when you press Ctrl+C.

Comment: signal is an interrupt. It has to be handled by using the relevant system calls.

Comment: You could try putting the terminal in raw mode, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217250/2485966

Comment: Linux [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) actually recommend to avoid `signal` in favour of `sigaction`.

Comment: Be aware that catching signals is really easy – handling them comes with some pitfalls you need to be aware of, though. For instance you should only call [signal safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Signals work pretty much like yet another thread, but they won't be preempted by those normal threads. This means, for instance, that you shouldn't ever wait on mutexes either, because if they are locked, there's no-one left to unlock them again, so deadlock...

Comment: @Bib and all the others recommending catching the signal: Yes, it's easy, but it is *not* the "only way"! And if you really want to read control-C as an ordinary input character, it's completely the wrong way to do it.  Turning off the interrupt character in the terminal driver, or putting the terminal driver in raw mode, are the right ways to do it.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question.  The OP *specifically asked* for a way to read control-C without catching it as a signal.  Someone closed the question as a duplicate, pointing at a former question explaining how to catch control-C as a signal.  I have seen no indication that this is an XY program, that the OP is wrong, that the OP should be wanting to catch the signal instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to "read CTL+C as input" instead of having it generate a `SIGINT` it is necessary [to use `tcsetattr`()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) to either clear `cc_c[VINTR]` or clear the `ISIG` flag as described in the manual page that I linked to, here.

You will need to use `tcgetattr`, first, to read the current terminal settings, adjust them accordingly, then `tcsetattr` to set them.

You should make sure that the terminal settings get reset to their original defaults when your program terminates, it is not a given that the shell will reset them to default, for you.

Comment: While this is true, it is not very likely to be of service to OP. In spite of asking to read control-C as a character, that is probably not going to do them much good. Especially by itself—once those flags are cleared, what character does the control-C key combination send, and, given other default settings, does it cause the buffer to be sent or does one need to make other changes to cause characters to be sent immediately? (Because, if it is not sent immediately, the user will press control-C and then expect some immediate program response, but the program will still be waiting for input.)

Comment: Perhaps, @EricPostpischil, the OP wants to reimplement emacs, where ^C is a valid key command, or a part of one, and there's nothing wrong with reading it from standard input and acting on it accordingly. In any case, whether or not it's useful to read ^C will be evaluated on its own merits once ^C becomes readable as an ordinary character. Even if it proves to be not, the original question that was asked is a perfectly reasonable, valid question, with an answer that precisely addresses what was asked.

Comment: You don't need to do that.  This willl make your program to handle in a different way when the input comes from a tty, while the ttty has an escape character for this purpose.  Read my answer for a solution that requires no programming at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `signal()` is not the way.  You should need to configure the `tty` driver to do **raw input** (no input char processing in the driver), so it passes all characters untouched. But this requires considering the `tty` input device as special and write special code to treat that case (this requires you to issue several `ioctl` system calls).  But this is not recommended, for the reasons explained below.

Second, there's another, simpler way that doesn't require to use raw mode.  You can *escape* the Ctrl-C character by prepending the `tty` *escape character.*  In Linux and BSD system, this is normally tied to the Ctrl-V character, so pressing Ctrl-V + Ctrl-C allows you to input a single Ctrl-C char.  I have just checked it with the `hd` command:

```
$ hd
^C
00000000 : 03 0a                                           : ..
00000002
$ _
```

Next question is, then, how to input a Ctrl-V?  well, just double it! (but we are out of scope now, just continue reading)

The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require programming in your program and will work the same way when reading from a file, pipe, fifo, socket, etc. (to which Ctrl-C has no special meaning, as the `tty` driver is out of scene)  The only device that generates an interrupt when detecting Ctrl-C is the `tty` driver (more exactly, the controlling `tty`,  in it's code generic part, so all `tty`s do this) and it also has a escape character (by the same reason, all `tty`s have it) to invalidate the special meaning of the next character.

You can check which character is the escape character with the `stty(1)` command, configured as the `lnext` entry.  But I can almost ensure you that it will be Ctrl-V.

## Note

This also applies to any other special character (like Ctrl-D, Ctrl-H, etc. that the terminal uses for special purposes)