# can I avoid displaying ^C while writing in the standard input?

Tags: c, terminal

I'm trying to read from the standard input and I'd like to avoid displaying expressions such as ^C or ^D when pressing ctrl+C ....
I'm only allowed to use tcsetattr and tcgetattr functions.

```
int main() {
    while(1) {};
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch Ctrl-C in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c)

Comment: The way control characters are echoed by the terminal is controlled by the `ECHOCTL` flag in the `c_lflag` member of the `struct termios` sent to the the terminal by `tcsetattr()`. If the flag is not set, control characters will be echoed as raw characters. This flag is an extension to the POSIX / Open Group specification. See your system's "termios" man page for details.